# netcat echo server - possible with pipes instead of commands as strings?

Tags: netcat

I want to create an echo server without specifying any of my commands inside strings. I want all commands to be connected by pipes.

This doesn't appear possible because the response gets returned before the request can be passed to the response generating logic. It seems I could use ncat but I also would prefer to avoid that.

I thought it might be possible with a fifo queue but I'm having trouble getting this to work.

**The "What I'm trying to do" part**

Attempting to justify these restrictions is challenging with my limited verbal skills. But my ultimate goal is to maintain a master script of all my web application logic with the convenience of xinetd (but without daemons). Such a master script might have dozens of lines like these:

```
nc -l 8080 | get_person_name.sh | create_insert_statement.sh | sqlplus
nc -l 8081 | get_person_id.sh | create_select_statement.sh | sqlplus
```

The 2nd one won't work because it won't be able to return the output to the client. So I'm reducing the problem to implementing an echo server with netcat. I don't want to use strings because all those commands will be dynamic and I just don't want to deal with that extra level of indirection (for a start, my text editor will have far less useful syntax highlighting). I'd be open to a here document solution though.

Comment: A fifo pipe is indeed the answer.